# can java be used to create desktop apps like dropbox?

Tags: web-applications, web, desktop-application, synchronization

I was going to create a desktop app which syncs file with the web.

**In short it is EXACTLY going to be like how DROPBOX works.**

Just wanted to know whether such a thing is possible with Java? If not, or if there is a BETTER way of doing this, please tell me...

Thanks in advance !! :)

Comment: Yes, it's possible. What make you thinks that it is not?

Comment: in short; yes it can and yes there *possibly* is a 'better' way.

Comment: @Thilo :
Thanks for replying mate...

Btw, can you specify the major differences between using Python or Java for the above mentioned task....?

Thanks ! :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do ***almost*** anything you can do in other programming language while using Java, the only difference is how long it'll take you, how fast it'll execute, etc.

The answer is, YES. You can make an executable .jar file that will copy all the files in a specific folder to an online server. Then to gain access to the server, you have your "dropbox" program on different computers with a login screen and connect your program to the server, then pull all data from the server to copy it to the local folder.

Then make more advanced configurations such as syncing every few seconds/every time a file is modified, locking files when one person is working on a specific file to prevent the file corrupting.

It's possible, and sounds like an interesting project, but it probably isn't for the faint of heart (depending on how complicated you go). Have fun.